# Los datos ingresados en un formulario Javascript arrojan undefined y no se almacenan adecuadamente en el array

Tags: javascript, array, formularios, undefined

En esta especie de formulario con dos inputs donde se intenta llenar un array con los datos que el usuario introduce por ambos inputs hay un problema y es que al querer almacenar los inputs de los usuarios como datos de los nuevos objetos de tipo "Usuario" en el array vacío, aparecen pero como "undefined" y no encuentro el error

```
//Creación de variables para registrar las entradas de los usuarios.
let entradaNombre = "";
let entradaContraseña = "";

//Creación de la clase Usuario. Parametros: id, mail y contraseña de los usuarios.
class Usuario{
    constructor(idUsuario,mail,contraseña){
        this.idUsuario = parseInt(idUsuario);
        this.mail = mail;
        this.contraseña = contraseña;
    }
}

//Inicialización del array donde se guardarán los objetos, en este caso la información de los usuarios.
const usuarios = [];

//Obtención del mail/nombre del usuario
let ingresoNombreUsuario = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1");
ingresoNombreUsuario.onchange = () => {
    console.log(ingresoNombreUsuario.value);
}
//obtención de la contraseña del usuario
let ingresarContraseñaUsuario = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1");
ingresarContraseñaUsuario.onchange = () =>{
    console.log(ingresarContraseñaUsuario.value);
}

usuarios.push(new Usuario(1,ingresoNombreUsuario.value,ingresarContraseñaUsuario.value));

//Obtengo y almaceno mi formulario desde el DOM.
let formularioDeUsuarios = document.getElementById("registroUsuarios");

//Creo un evento a través de una función arrow.
formularioDeUsuarios.onsubmit = (event) => {
    //El event.preventDefault() evita que se refresque la página.
    event.preventDefault();
    //Se indica a la función flecha que debe bajar el ambito a lo local.
    //Que se quede con el evento de ese momento.
    event.target;
    
    const inputs = formularioDeUsuarios.children;
    usuarios.push(new Usuario(0,inputs[0].value,inputs[1].value));
    console.log(usuarios);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero, tienes un typo en onsubmit(), lo estas escribiendo todo en minusculas, y la "s" va en mayuscula.

Aun así no va a funcionar, no uses onSubmit(). Para eventos usa el metodo addEventListenner(). De esa forma, tu función quedará:

```
formularioDeUsuarios.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.target

  const inputs = formularioDeUsuarios.children
  usuarios.push(new Usuario(0, inputs[0].value, inputs[1].value))
  console.log(usuarios)
})
```

Así a mi me funcionó.

Comment: probé tu respuesta y no me funcionó... incluso en un IDE online para asegurarme de que no era problema con VSC... al ingresar los datos por los inputs y clickear fuera, se escucha el evento sin problemas, pero al darle click al botón "Send", los datos de ambos inputs se pushean al array pero "undefined" y no encuentro el error... tal como inicié el post